# Unicode characters not appearing:   ט  ط

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode, xecjk

I'm attempting to get the following line to compile in XeLaTex:

```
The letter   (also written  , ט, , ط , or þ)
```

All but ט and þ do not appear when compiling with XeLaTex using the following packages:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Any idea how to get these to appear? My operating system displays these fine in its default text editor and on this browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! First, you shouldn't use `inputenc` with utf8 based engines (XeTeX and LuaTeX). However the problem is probably that the font you are using doesn't contain those glyphs. With the standard font (Latin Modern I get this warnings in the log: `Missing character: There is no  in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!`, once for each of `טط`.

Comment: if you use the inspector tools in your browser you can see which font it is using, and use the same font in xetex, here your question uses Segoe UI Historic

Comment: Browsers have rules for using fallbacks fonts. XeTeX hasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XeLaTex doesn't fallback on fonts for characters it doesn't know. 
First, no need to use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.
Use fonts for each character, here Segoe UI Historic works do this with:

```
\newfontfamily{\Segoe}{[Segoe_ui_historic.ttf]}
\Segoe{}
```

Find a compatible font for each character.